# How to configure Sentry Webpack sourcemap uploading in Quasar?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sentry, source-maps, quasar

I'm trying to follow the documentation of [Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/vue/sourcemaps/uploading/webpack/) to configure my Vue.js SPA application to report errors. Given the minification during build, Sentry requires the sourcemap, which is created by Webpack during build time. I'm manually creating this configuration file:

extendWebpack(cfg) {
cfg.entry = path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/main.js");

```
   extendWebpack(cfg) {
        cfg.entry = path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/main.js");
        
        cfg.devtool ="source-map";
        // Add Module Federation configuration here
        cfg.plugins.push(  
          sentryWebpackPlugin({
            project: "nds-ui-boot-sentry",
            org: "sentry",
            url: "https://sonario-nds.apps.ocp-new-dev.bri.co.id",
            authToken: "process.env.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN",
            release: "2.5.10",
            sourcemaps:{
              include:["./dist/assets"],
              ignore:["node_modules"],
              urlPrefix: "~/assets",
            }
            }),
```

But the source map does not appear in sentry. The code does not have an error. But in sentry the source map can't access the config.